# Issues with materials after Mixamo export/import

Tags: materials, export, mixamo

I'm a noobie and I'm starting to make assets to mod a game called StormGate (not out yet) that will be on Unreal Engine 5.

I have a grasp on modelling by now but animation looks very complex so I want to use automated tools as much as possible. Mixamo offers free rigging and free animations (they're not great but I can tweak them in Blender).

I have managed to export my models into the website and put them back in Blender with animations, however I have a few issues while doing it:

1. I can't upload anything in FBX, it works fine in .obj though (though when I get the FBX file with animation I have to export it at 100 scale to get the same size, weird)
2. Maybe because of this I lose all my materials when uploading to the website (I checked the export options and I only saw write materials related to that and it's checked)
3. It's not a big deal to put them back on, however I want all my characters to have a black outline so I'm using a solidy modifier with backface culling and material offset (I followed a tutorial) and the export-import process messes it up

[image: I would like to keep that outline]

So what would be the best workflow? Put the outline after the animations?
Maybe there's a way not to lose the materials?

Comment: There are some limitations on export and import in FBX format relating to materials. [This](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/scene_fbx.html#fbx/) is the link to the section on FBX import/export in the Blender manual.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures